# Unable to publish local repository to github

Tags: github, version-control, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am using github for source control for unreal engine 4. When I publish the branch to github, I get the following error

```
Enumerating objects: 2865, done.
Counting objects: 100% (2865/2865), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2832/2832), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 Send failure: Connection was reset
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedlyMiB | 1.75 MiB/s
Writing objects: 100% (2865/2865), 2.56 GiB | 14.18 MiB/s, done.
Total 2865 (delta 198), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: Maybe 2.56gb is too much for github?

Comment: hmm possibly...
is there anyway i can lower the size??

Comment: No idea, sorry. Never worked with UE4.

Comment: Check here https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/working-with-large-files and here https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/versioning-large-files

Comment: i couldnt find anything that helped :-(

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post but just in case...

Did you setup source control from within unreal or separately?
I believe doing it from within unreal itself would seriously reduce the size of the commits